# Add-ins cannot load in Windows 7

Tags: deployment, windows-7, vsto

I got a problem that my add-in not work in Win7, due to the add-ins is a policy program in company, so it's required to be install for all users and run every start-up.

In WinXP era, the add-in work using SetSecurity library by installer but it's not work in Win7 now, I have tried to re-create a deployment package of installer but it still unable to load.

I tried ClickOnce is work but if the program hasn't been install, it will prompt for ask install, due to the add-in is policy program which is required to run everytime, so it's not allow user to skip install.

I tried use microsoft add-ins example but tested it will prompt for ask install too.

Could anyone can help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by apply hotfix in [KB976477](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976477) Office 2007 with `EnableLocalMachineVSTO` registry setting.

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811